# Microsoft Certification Based Authentication - MC316448

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, basic-authentication, windows-authentication

I have received an email about the cert based auth from Microsoft

[image]

Now, I have a scenario where a couple of web apps are hosted on Windows servers. All the articles point to the changes for security defaults in Office 365 after March. I understand this is just for Exchange and other Microsoft apps.

I have the following queries regarding this security update:

1. Does this mean that the "Basic Authentication" feature in IIS will be deprecated?
2. How does this affect web apps which support multiple authentication methods? Basic, Windows and Azure AD?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic Authentication relies on sending usernames and passwords  -- often stored on or saved to the device -- with every request, increasing risk of attackers capturing users' credentials, particularly if not TLS protected.

> 1.Does this mean that the "Basic Authentication" feature in IIS will be deprecated?

***Answer***:-- As part of ***[security defaults](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/concept-fundamentals-security-defaults)***, Microsoft currently disable Basic Authentication by default for new customer and effective ***October 1, 2022***, Microsoft begin to permanently disable Basic Auth in all tenants, ***`regardless of usage`***, with the exception of SMTP Auth.

For more information you can follow this ***[MS Document](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/exchange-team-blog/basic-authentication-and-exchange-online-september-2021-update/ba-p/2772210)***

> 2.ow does this affect web apps which support multiple authentication methods? Basic, Windows and Azure AD?

***Answer***:-- For multiple authentications, Basic Auth will be disable rest you can use. Here is an advantage and consider a secure way of auth is which was not possible using Basic Auth. If you have a ***Windows Active Directory*** environment—users can be automatically signed into web applications using their domain account. Other built-in security features include TLS certificate management and binding for enabling HTTPS and SFTP on your sites, request filtering for whitelisting or blacklisting traffic, authorization rules, request logging, and a rich set of FTP-specific security options.

You can also refer this ***[Document](https://stackify.com/iis-web-server/)*** for more information

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Since none of the articles from Microsoft refers to IIS, my understanding is that the mentioned changes for the security defaults will only affect the users who are using Azure AD to log in and that would be prompting the users for MFA via Authenticator app and/or phone. Is that right?

Comment: @indu, Yes you are correct even i not finding any document the specific point for IIS and as in last document which i have shared is suggested to use AD or AAD rather than basic auth. In basic Auth there can be chances of attack . As Microsoft Already decied to deprecite this in upcoming month . So i belive Basic Auth will remove from everywhere inlcuing IIS as well as this is not more secure.

Comment: for more information you can reach out to support for IIS. : https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/support/options/#support-plans